# Smtp email on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cloud, google

The email sistems was working well but it beggun to have a mistake, it doesn´t send emails, support told me is a host provider problem, and the smtp show me this screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNVNO.png)

Comment: The error message says it clearly that you need OAuth2 authentication to Google servers. There probably is some OAuth2 plugin for Wordpress, you must install it & configure according to it's documentation.

Comment: It's within the plugin they are using, WP SMTP Mail, and authentication can be configured there.